# What type of hash is used to encrypt the Lenovo T61p hard-drive password?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, passwords, thinkpad

My computer (Lenovo T61p) broke recently, and I need to recover the information off my hard-drive. The hard-drive is password protected, and I know the password, however I also selected the "Use Passphrase" option in the Lenovo's bios settings, so it encrypted the password. This means the hard-drive password is the encrypted version rather than the one I know, and my new computer doesn't use the same encryption method, so I need to be able to recreate the encryption.

If there is a better way to approach this problem, that answer would be just as appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know of encryption (though that isn't much!), there would be a cryptographic salt incorporated in the algorithm so you would need more information than just the hash function. http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Full_Disk_Encryption_(FDE) has some info on Lenovo encryption; I think it says you can use the drive in another Lenovo computer.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Thanks for the link, I'll try using the master password to reset the user key like it suggested on that page, but I'm pretty sure I wasn't using full disk encryption, just a hard-drive password. Also, the only other Lenovo I have access to is a 3000 N200, which is apparently not similar enough to the T60 and T61.